# Several different multi user objects to single user

Tags: mesh, instances, data-blocks

What is the most effective workflow for making several (20) different multi-user models each into single user?

My use case is: I have 3 different objects each distributed manually several times through Alt-D (what I would call an instance). I now need to join all the 20 models into one mesh.

To get you all to my level I understand that I can make a unique copy of an object through Shift-D and an instance of an object through Alt-D. And I know I can click the number besides the object name in the Object Data panel to make it single user. I have no idea how to do this as a batch operation.

To be honest I am having a hard time grasping the terminology used to describe blenders instantiation of 3D objects (multiuser, single user, data block). I come from a 3Ds max background where an object instance means that changes made to an object is in effect in all instances of that object.

Comment: if you want all your object to have the same mesh, select them all, select the one with the good mesh at the end (it's now the "active" object), press Ctrl L (Make Links) > Object Data (or through the bar menu > Object > ...). Is it what you want?

Comment: Not exactly, but you put me in the right direction. I apparently wanted to go to the bar menu: **Object/Relations/Make Single User/Object and Data** and then afterwards (still with all the objects selected) joining them. So thanks :)

Comment: oh ok perfect then  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Through the bar menu i could make all the instances unique objects through: Object/Relations/Make Single User/Object and Data and then afterwards (still with all the objects selected) join them as I would normally through Ctrl-J.