# Moving origin changes origin and position of other objects too

Tags: modeling, objects, origin

I have a premade car model with separate wheels. For game purposes I need to move wheel origin.

For some reason when ever I move one wheel origin others get their origin and position changed too.

I can't figure out what is the reason of this. Can't find any modifiers or relations to each other so what I should be looking for?

Comment: Maybe these objects share the same mesh? (They are linked-duplications)

Comment: sorry, but without seeing any settings - we can just guess. Since it seems like you are a Blender beginner i would recommend providing your blend file because this can have lots of reasons: e.g. drivers, constraints, parent, armature...etc.

Comment: Are your objects instances? (Sharing mesh data) If so this may be a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/193148/35559

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you very much. Could you write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct one.

Comment: Hi Jani .. glad it's good! Nothing personal, but we try to keep the archive as tidy as we can for future users. You weren't to know, but this turns out to be a duplicate question, so can be closed. Don't let that inhibit you from asking your next question :)